# Replace values in one column in R matrix with another

Tags: r, matrix, replace

This was supposed to be simple. I have the following matrix p in R:

```
FoldChange  p-value Adjusted-p
0.149709239 2.62E-07    7.87E-07
2.245737455 0.001579041 0.003158083
87.47550188 0.278139481 0.333767377
9.74650534  0.271301337 0.333767377
1.707153155 3.02E-10    1.36E-09
0.262355958 2.26E-34    4.06E-33
80.1573117  0.235486226 0.326057851
0.980413329 0.840774427 0.840774427
0.405064954 6.52E-09    2.35E-08
29.03755354 0.008412822 0.012619233
1.166334836 0.002802483 0.004710189
1.299657545 2.61E-06    6.70E-06
0.70977405  0.613656995 0.649754466
0.170424757 3.33E-12    3.00E-11
0.090662919 0.002878449 0.004710189
10.99258642 0.362150281 0.407419067
Inf 9.44E-05    0.000212387
0.365164491 5.37E-12    3.22E-11
```

My goal is to replace the "Inf" in the first column only (FoldChange) into "100".

```
p[!is.finite(p[,"FoldChange"])] <- 100
```

When I try the command above, the output change the whole row where Inf is there to "100", so i get:

```
FoldChange  p-value Adjusted-p
0.149709239 2.62E-07    7.87E-07
2.245737455 0.001579041 0.003158083
87.47550188 0.278139481 0.333767377
9.74650534  0.271301337 0.333767377
1.707153155 3.02E-10    1.36E-09
0.262355958 2.26E-34    4.06E-33
80.1573117  0.235486226 0.326057851
0.980413329 0.840774427 0.840774427
0.405064954 6.52E-09    2.35E-08
29.03755354 0.008412822 0.012619233
1.166334836 0.002802483 0.004710189
1.299657545 2.61E-06    6.70E-06
0.70977405  0.613656995 0.649754466
0.170424757 3.33E-12    3.00E-11
0.090662919 0.002878449 0.004710189
10.99258642 0.362150281 0.407419067
100 100 100
0.365164491 5.37E-12    3.22E-11
```

I did try so many different combinations including for loops. I am not sure why I always get this output. Please advise.

Comment: `p[!is.finite(p[,"FoldChange"]), 'FoldChange'] <- 100`?

Comment: YES! thank you! that works